# Automatic browser login to Salesforce with SSO when user is logged into M365 -AzureAD-?

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

We would like to have Salesforce detect Azure AD user is logged in on the browser (chromium) and use that for automatic sign in. Possible?

Will salesforce look at the logged in windows user and use sso automatically to sign them in? We have SSO turned on and we get prompted every time.

Comment: A quick Google search produces many results,  e g. [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/salesforce-tutorial). Or have I missed something? I guess this is the reason someone downvoted your question. Why not just give it a try?

Comment: I understand. We currently have SSO turned on but prompts us for login when going to salesforce. I’m asking if we can have it automatically sign in when logged into m365. If we only have one provider will it automatically try to pick up the logged in user credentials and log them in?

Comment: _if we only have one provider will it automatically try to pick up the logged in user credentials and log them in_ : have you tried this? If so, please edit your question and show us the result.

Comment: I will try this once things are setup and report back.